# OpenFL windows, android target project build failed with empty error message in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, haxe, openfl

I use intellij-idea to develop OpenFL application.

But, build failed  with empty error message.
In Flash develop, build was succeeded, no errors.

and neko target project was succeeded in intellij-idea.

this is error screenshot.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/4wQx0mG.png]

and this is code of main class.

```
haxe package;
import openfl.display.Sprite;
class Main extends Sprite { 
public function new () {        
    super ();               
}   
}
```

I google about this errors but I can't resolve this problem.
I think this is OpenFL bug about hxcpp.

And I wondering that on my other pc, build was succeeded.

Comment: It seems unlikely that this is an OpenFL or Hcxpp bug when it's working fine in FlashDevelop - it's more likely that InteliJ is feeding the wrong build command to lime-tools or something like that. Can you see the command that InteliJ is running? FlashDevelop shows it in the output panel.

Comment: This is build log. http://pastebin.com/hnnH1KVF

Comment: I have had the same error, someone has any idea about this ?

Comment: I found a cause of this problem.Plugin bug cause this problem...Old version of plugin hadn't this problem. If you want to Intellij to writing haxe, you must wait to update. I recommend use other IDE or old version of this plugin. I use vim plugin "vaxe".

Comment: OpenFL forum has a suggestion to use TiVo's version of the plugin at http://github.com/TiVo/intellij-haxe

Comment: thanks. I try to use this plugin